# Finder Can't find the folder message: Why?

Tags: ios, iphone, finder

Am running an iOS app on my iPhone, and logged the Documents directory and .plist file path. Have just changed the data model, so I need to get to my .plist and delete the original file.

Went to Finder, pressed Command + Shift + G, and pasted in the path at /var/mobile/Applications/92F57312-E569-4B56-B639-92210CE94828/Documents/Checklists.plist

But when I pressed Go in the dialog box, I got a "Folder can't be found" message.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/var/mobile/Applications/92F57312-E569-4B56-B639-92210CE94828/Documents/Checklists.plist` is the file path on the iOS device itself, and has no relevance to your OS X drive and its files.

You should be able to use the Devices pane in the Xcode Organizer window to access files in the Documents folder on the device, or in iTunes (provided your app specifies that it allows that type of access).

Comment: Figured out the best way to solve problem: Just delete the app and re-install the app again. Thank you.